# Deriving Enum for a sum type of records in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a sum type of records to represent all in-memory tables and as I will send them across the network. I have a binary protocol and need to initially pass the ordinal value (fromEnum) in the header to determine which table the data is associated with. The problem is that the sum type needs to derive from Enum but it doesn't want to.

```
data Table = MarketData {bid::[Float], ask::[Float]}
     | Trade {price::[Float], qty::[Float]} 
        deriving Enum

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ fromEnum Trade
```

This is the compilation error

```
Can't make a derived instance of `Enum Table':
  `Table' must be an enumeration type
  (an enumeration consists of one or more nullary, non-GADT constructors)
In the data declaration for `Table'
```

Any ideas of how I can do this without having to write boilerplate like this:

```
ordinalVal :: Table -> Int
ordinalVal tbl = case tbl of
      MarketData{bid=_, ask=_} -> 0
    | Trade{price=_, qty=_} -> 1
```

Comment: Small tip on reducing the boilerplate: When pattern matching a record, you don't need to list fields you are not using. So you could just have `MarketData{} -> 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to enumerate the constructors, you can you the [Data.Data](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#t%3aDataType) module, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
import Data.Data

data T a b = C1 a b | C2 deriving (Typeable, Data)

main = print $ constrIndex $ toConstr x
  where
    x :: T Int Int
    x = C1 1 1  -- will print 1
    -- x = C2  -- will print 2
```

If you don't want to go down the road of using the `Typebale` and `Data` type classes, you could also simply write a function `Table -> Int`, like you proposed.

Comment: I need to keep to record syntax as the field access methods are used across my code.

Comment: @jap `data T a b = C1 a b | C2` was just an example; you should be able to keep using records regardless. (Note that mixing records and sum types does not work very well; it makes partial record labels and accessors possible.)